# Where can I find ACS data for *specific* countries of origin and languages spoken at home?

Tags: us-census

I wanted to map out where Ethiopians live in the Puget Sound area. ArcGIS has mapped ACS data, but I could only find data for places of birth [grouped by continent](https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=f0dd0af9535e4d77864df1b728e4b162).  Same with [languages spoken](https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=527ea2b5ba814c8ca1c34a2945e1b751). What I really want is data that shows how many people came from "Ethiopia", or speak "Amharic" at home (or Oromo, Tigrinya, etc.) Does such data exist?

I'd also like to drill down into specific ethnicities, e.g. Arabs and Kurds, Sinhalese vs. Tamil, Kinh vs. Hmong. After all, many people of Ethiopian descent were born in the United States! Does the ACS even have data that specific?

Comment: yes!  this exists at the _PUMA_ level.  https://www.census.gov/programs-surveys/acs/microdata.html  you might need to work with the microdata directly